# How do I return rows with a specific value first and rest all the values of a table in a Alphabetic order

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to get `book_name` and `book_code` order `by book_name` in alphabetic order.

I have three tables:

**Table1**:

```
Books (Independent Table which will have all the books)
```

**Table2**:

```
Authors (Independent Table which will have all the authors)
```

**Table3**:

```
Author_Books(This table will provide the information about which book is which author's primary book.)
```

**Note**: One Author can have many books.

Input to my query is **Author_code**.

1. If I pass Author_code I need to get the primary book of that 
        Author as first row one and rest all books in a table should come order by book_name in alphabetic
2. If I don't pass any input to my query I need all the books in 
       alphabetic order.

My query returns author's default book:

```
SELECT book_CD, book_NAM 
from books 
where Alpha_NUM_book_CD 
           = (SELECT Alpha_NUM_book_CD 
              from Author_Book
              JOIN Author 
              on Author.NUM_Author_CD = Author_Book.NUM_Author_CD 
               where Author.NUM_Author_CD
                      = (SELECT NUM_Author_CD 
                         from Author 
                         where ALPHA_3_Author_CD = '') 
              AND Author_Book.PRIM_book_SW = 'Y'
   );
```

How to write a query which satisfies both my cases?

We are using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Two queries, which reveal the same columns, may be joined by q1 union q2, don't they? I didn't use SQL for a long time... :)

Answer (score 0):

The `order by` can take multiple keys.  So, something like this:

```
order by (case when author.NUM_Author_CD = ? then 1 else 2 end),
         book.title
```

Comment: Can you reconstruct my complete query please. The query I posted is only half piece I guess.

Comment: @DineshRao . . . That should not be necessary.  Your question is about ordering, and ordering only requires an `order by` clause.  If your current query is not working you should ask *another* question about that.